# Doesn't the contract need to enforce that Oracle has signed the Fix command in IRS example?

Tags: corda

I observed that normally in a typical contract we have something similar to

```
"The signers should be the participants for the state" using
(command.signers.toSet() == state.participants.map { it.owningKey }.toSet())
```

where we enforce if this specific command is used, the required signers are equal to the participants (assuming participants of the deal are always mandatory to sign) so nodes don't maliciously change the flow to sidestep getting signatures from some parties.

In the IRS demo on Oracle (`RateFixFlow/NodeInterestRate`), the [State](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/d3495e12c692cb50a711ba11ee7f1c707e5c384e/samples/irs-demo/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/irs/contract/IRS.kt#L600) has the `participants` and `oracle` parties involved. There's also a [verifyFixCommand](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/d3495e12c692cb50a711ba11ee7f1c707e5c384e/samples/irs-demo/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/irs/contract/IRS.kt#L513) that verifies some rules are met whenever a Fix command was used to get the rates from the Oracle.

Why doesn't the command also enforce that participants must have signed - plus the oracle must sign as well to guarantee the Fix rates was validated by the Oracle? Else why have the flow get the oracle's signature at all. What's stopping the initiator from bypassing getting the oracle signature in the first place.

Was there any rationale behind not putting a similar rule from the below in? i.e

`"The signers should be the participants and oracle for the state" using
    (command.signers.toSet() == 
(state.participants.map { it.owningKey } + state.oracle.owningKey).toSet())`

Comment: IMHO, I think the Contracts need to be deterministic in nature as a result it's not available.

Comment: possibly an oversight - one of the contract requirements within verify should check to confirm the oracle has signed

Answer (score 0):

This is an oversight. The contract's `verify` method should check the required signers.

It would be appreciated if you could create a PR to amend this. The contribution guides are here: https://docs.corda.net/contributing.html.